# How can I restore photos and videos from an iPhone back up?

Tags: iphone

How can I get my photos and videos that were backed up from my iPhone 5 onto my iPhone 6?

Comment: Restore your iPhone 6 from the same backup in iTunes. Just plug your device in and select it in the devices menu and choose restore. Disable find my iPhone first if it's enabled

Answer (score -2):

Use your iCloud ID or send via Bluetooth coppy your file ent back up and go to settings choose erase all content restart your phone login your ICloud ID restore it .

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.